# Optimizing a problem in OpenMDAO so that objective takes specific value

Tags: python, openmdao

I want to know if it is possible to optimize a problem in OpenMDAO in such a way that the objective approaches a specified value rather than minimizing or maximizing the objective?

For example:

```
prob.model.add_objective("objective1", equals=10)
```

as in specifying constraints is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not specify an equality for the objective like that. You could specify a given objective, then secondarily add an equality constraint for that same value. This is technically valid, but it would be a very strange way to pose an optimization problem.

If you have a specific design variable you hope to vary to satisfy the equality constraint, then you probably don't want to do an optimization at all. Instead, you likely want to use a solver. You can use solvers to vary just one variable, or potentially more than one (as long as you have one equality constraint per variable). An generic example of using a solver can be found here, [setting up a basic nonlinear circit analysis](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.17.0/examples/circuit_analysis_examples.html).

However, in your case you more likely want to use a [BalanceComp](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.17.0/features/building_blocks/components/balance_comp.html). You can set a specific fixed value into the right hand side of the balance, using an init argument like this:

```
bal = BalanceComp()
bal.add_balance('x', val=1.0, rhs_val=3.0)
```

Then you can connect the variable you want to hold fixed to that value to the left hand side of the balance.